# Calculate exponential weighted sum in Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

Go straight to the example problem I have on hand.

I have the following example dataframe for illustration:

```
import polars as pl

decay = 0.8

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [7, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5, 5, 7],
        "index": [5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9],
        "x": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0],
    }
)
```

I want to calculate the exponentially weighted rolling sum (rolling window is 3 in this example for simplicity) for each `id` and window index is `index` (the index difference determines the window, for example, for window size = 3, the index difference has to be <= 3). More explicitly, the result I want is:

```
id   index   x
1    7       1.0
1    8       1.555
5    7       1.0
5    8       2.111
5    9       2.475
7    5       1.0
7    7       1.0
7    9       3.439
```

To provide extra clarify about the results above:

```
for id 1 and index 8, the result should be (2*1 + 1*0.8) / (1 + 0.8) = 1.555
for id 5 and index 9, the result should be (3*1 + 3*0.8 + 1*0.8*0.8) / (1 + 0.8 + 0.8*0.8) = 2.475
for id 7 and index 9, the result should be (5*1 + 1*0.8*0.8) / (1 + 0.8*0.8) = 3.439
```

If my real dataframe is very large, what could be an efficient algorithm to achieve what I want?

Note: the window size here is just 3 for illustration purpose. In reality, the window size is a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The question's been updated to further clarify that the `x` column is actually important: it is the coefficients of each term on the top of the fraction of the final `x` calcuation.

Combining @jqurious 's refinement of my answer with this information gives us:

```
def decay_rolling(lazy_df, decay=0.8, window_size=3):

    shifts_idx = (pl.col('index').shift(w).over('id').alias(f't{w}') for w in range(window_size))
    shifts_x = (pl.col('x').shift(w).over('id').alias(f'x{w}') for w in range(window_size))

    bottom = 1 + sum(
        pl.when(pl.col(f"t{w}").is_not_null())
            .then(decay ** (pl.col('t0') - pl.col(f"t{w}")))
            .otherwise(0)
        for w in range(1, window_size)
    )
    top = pl.col('x0') + sum(
        pl.when(pl.col(f"t{w}").is_not_null())
            .then(pl.col(f"x{w}") * decay ** (pl.col("t0") - pl.col(f"t{w}")))
            .otherwise(0)
        for w in range(1, window_size)
    )

    # combine all. sorting first is not required but looks nicer.
    return (
        lazy_df.sort("id", "index")
        .with_columns(shifts_idx)
        .with_columns(shifts_x)
        .select('id', 'index', x = top / bottom)
        .collect()
    )
```

Again, I don't think this is possible with the `groupby_rolling` (no ewm_sum aggregation in polars currently) or `rolling_sum` (no way to alter weights from group to group).

Comment: Previously I just made it simple the column x, but that accidentally renders x useless.

Comment: Thanks! do you think there will be some room for optimizations for large dataframes? Or, this should be very efficient already?

Comment: For a df of height 100k of random values between 0-99 for all columns, I am getting roughly 20-22ms execution time. For 1 million rows, 250-350ms. It starts blowing up at 10 mil rows, 5-6 seconds.

Comment: what's your machine spec roughly?

Comment: Sorry, seems like your solution still has a bit miss-understanding. Updated the post again. Window index differences determines the group, not the count.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. It seems the built-in `ewm` methods in Polars don't have any `sum`, so I just went ahead and did the nitty-gritty calculations straight up. I believe I understood the problem (over each `id`, the minimum `index` is set to a "time value" of 1, and so on).

I made it a method so I could `timeit` easier:

```
def decay_rolling(lazy_df, decay=0.8):
    # we need a lot of expressions used more than once,
    # for readability this is best done in variables.
    
    # we need three temporary columns of the index values, over ID,
    # in a relative time series (first value = 1, rest the difference to that value)
    # as well as two shifted columns so we can use up to three data points
    # in each row (rolling window).
    # note these expressions need an over('id'), that is finalized below.
  
    temp = pl.col("index") - pl.col("index").min() + 1
    temp_1 = temp.shift()
    temp_2 = temp.shift(2)

    # now four decay expressions, which will add appropriate values
    # to the top/bottom of the fraction, or 0 if null.
    # note the column references match up with an intermediate with_columns below.

    decay_bottom_1 = (
        pl.when(pl.col("t1").is_not_null())
        .then(decay ** (pl.col("t0") - pl.col("t1")))
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    decay_bottom_2 = (
        pl.when(pl.col("t2").is_not_null())
        .then(decay ** (pl.col("t0") - pl.col("t2")))
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    decay_top_1 = (
        pl.when(pl.col("t1").is_not_null())
        .then(pl.col("t1") * decay ** (pl.col("t0") - pl.col("t1")))
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    decay_top2 = (
        pl.when(pl.col("t2").is_not_null())
        .then(pl.col("t2") * decay ** (pl.col("t0") - pl.col("t2")))
        .otherwise(0)
    )

    # combine all. sorting first is important.
    return df.with_columns(
        t.over("id").alias(f"t{e}") for e, t in enumerate((temp, temp_1, temp_2))
    ).with_columns(
        x=(pl.col("t0") + decay_top_1 + decay_top_2)
        / (1 + decay_bottom_1 + decay_bottom_2)
    ).select(pl.exclude('^t\d$'))
```

This works within 1-2ms on my machine on the test df above (I excluded the `x` column, and sorted by `id` beforehand). For a "real" df of 100000 rows of random values, this works within 10-15ms. For 10 mil rows, ~3.5 seconds.

Comment: thanks, expect a much simpler solution though. Is it possible to do this using something like groupby_rolling?

Comment: I think groupby_rolling matches groupby_dynamic in that it is `a window size determined by dates/times/values instead of slots in the DataFrame`. So I don't think that is possible here.

There is [rolling_sum](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_sum.html#polars.Expr.rolling_sum) which I looked at, but the weights have to be a static list of floats, which also doesn't work here.

Comment: In my example, window should be determined by the 'index' column. For example, id 7 with index 9 are grouped with id 7 with index 7 when window size is 3.

Comment: But what if indexes are non-contiguous? I don't see a way to specify a constant window size with these methods. Unless I am misunderstanding the problem statement.

Comment: For id 7, its index is dissentious already. The window is based on index.

Comment: @Keptain It sounds like you're describing: `df.groupby_dynamic(by="id", index_column="index", every="3i", start_by="datapoint").agg(pl.col("index").suffix("_"), pl.col("x").ewm_mean(half_life=0.8))` (mean just used as an example here as there is no sum as has been mentioned - maybe it could get added?)

Comment: @jqurious  I tried ewm and to me it cannot handle 'id 7 and index 9' case in my example.

Comment: @Keptain Is the `groupby_dynamic` providing the correct grouping you need though? (I don't really understand the math, sorry.)

Comment: @jqurious yes, I think the grouping is correct. for id 7 and index 9, its group is id=7 index=7 x=1, and id=7 index=9 x=3, ewm will do 3 +1*0.8 whereas I want 3 + 1*0.8*0.8 as there is a gap between index=7 and index=9.

Comment: @Wayoshi Seems like your solution only works for the case of window size = 3. Is it possible to extend your solution to make it work with any window size?

Comment: @Wayoshi I think you may have some understanding of my problem. I just updated my original post with some other numbers and your solution does not work.